# Does every kid see the same thing haunting them?

Tags: plot-explanation, it-2017

Regarding the 2017 ***IT*** movie - I was wondering if every kid in the movie sees the same thing haunting them.  I understand it's their 'fear' but I'm not sure if it's one of the following:

1. Every kid sees a different form of 'fear', i.e. some see the clown, the other one sees a distorted painting figure / rotten zombie /etc
2. Every kid sees a different monster AND the clown
3. Everything is shared (i.e. the clown changes form throughout the movie) and the kids see them all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It, aka Pennywise, is an alien. It is also a shapeshifter, whose true form looks like a spider.

Pennywise normally appears as an evil clown holding a red balloon. But can shapeshift into other monstrous forms based on whom Pennywise is trying to terrify.

When It shapeshifts, every kid can see it. There are at least two scenes that I can recall from this movie:

- Georgie without an arm: everyone can see it.
- Woman with a distorted face biting on one of the kid: everyone can see it.

Comment: thanks!  As my question to nthtung, the scene after the kids explore the sewage near the barren, where one of the bullies holding a spray with a lighter and is killed. The bully saw more than one aliens, which makes me think there are multiple of them aliens

Comment: @Alex, there is only one IT. You can think of multiple "things" as a way to shapeshift. When Pennywise shapeshifts, IT produces multiple demonic presences.

Comment: It isn't an alien in the conventional sense - it's from a different realm. A realm of existence that is outside of our universe. Think of It kind of like a 'god' or a trans-dimensional being.  It is one thing, but it can manifest as many things. It's reach is also the entire town of Derry, but it can extend further (making the kids, as adults, forget).

Answer (score 4):

The story was told from different perspective but all included the "clown" vision. All the kids saw "IT" as a clown, and they also saw IT morphed into their feared thoughts. So it should be the option c) that you listed.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  That means for e.g. Beverly sees a clown and her father's image, where Edward won't see Beverly's father but a clown and the rotten zombie?  It all seems make sense except the one of the bullies that killed by the clown - he saw not 1 but numbers of rotten things - which leads to my suspect that there's more than just 1 clown

Comment: Are you referring to the near end scene in the sewer when IT continuously tried to morph into different images ? I believe at that point all the kids learned that IT could shapeshift into their fears; thus at that very time they all saw IT in different shapes.

Comment: Referring to the scene after the kids explore the sewage near the barren, where one of the bullies holding a spray with a lighter and is killed.  the bully saw more than 1...thing

Comment: It's just the demoniac presence that "IT" created, and it doesn't mean there are more than one "IT". You can read this article to know more about the background of "IT" http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/It_(creature)

Comment: It was attempting to feed off the fears of the various kids - when they stood up to It and weren't afraid, It lost it's power. So, at the end, it was cycling through the kids *trying to scare at least one of them*. It can only take form of one being at a time and It is bound by whatever 'laws' that being possesses (so it couldn't become a frog with super strength, for example).

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles so technically instead of feed off from the kid's 'creepy fear',  IT can transform into a lion and feed off from 'instinct fear' which is kinda not limited to kids?  I know i might go a little too far here

Comment: "It" can transform into literally everything but it would always prefer the frightful image directly from the victim's mind (from what I have learnt in the movie and the book). If its victim's fear was a lion at that time, yes, it will transform itself into a lion.

Comment: @Alex, from what I understand (the book and the websites) It **does** feed off the physical and 'psychic' energies. King, and his universe, is big on psychic energy type stuff. I can't remember what he actually calls it.  Anyway, so **yes** It would feed off the 'instinct fear' from the kids. The reason It (which is a female, I think) likes kids is because their fears are easier to manipulate (I suppose It could transform into a boss and fire an adult, but I digress).  That's not to say that It doesn't feed on adults - it does, often.